# Erro na chamada de função arrow em botão - React Native

Tags: funções, react, react-native, mobile, arrow-functions

quero chamar a função clearMemory pelo botão "AC" mas não estou conseguindo.

Segue o código de referência:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    displayValue: '0',
  }

  addDigit = n => {
    this.setState({ displayValue: n })
  }

  clearMemory = () => {
    this.setState({ displayValue: 0 })
  }

  setOperation = operation => {
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Display value={this.state.displayValue} />
        <View style={styles.buttons}>
          <Button label='AC' triple onclick={this.clearMemory} />
          <Button label='/' operation onClick={() => this.setOperation('/')} />
          <Button label='7' onClick={() => this.addDigit(7)} />
          <Button label='8' onClick={() => this.addDigit(8)} />
          <Button label='9' onClick={() => this.addDigit(9)} />
          <Button label='*' operation onClick={() => this.setOperation('*')} />
          <Button label='4' onClick={() => this.addDigit(4)} />
          <Button label='5' onClick={() => this.addDigit(5)} />
          <Button label='6' onClick={() => this.addDigit(6)} />
          <Button label='-' operation onClick={() => this.setOperation('-')} />
          <Button label='1' onClick={() => this.addDigit(1)} />
          <Button label='2' onClick={() => this.addDigit(2)} />
          <Button label='3' onClick={() => this.addDigit(3)} />
          <Button label='+' operation onClick={() => this.setOperation('+')} />
          <Button label='0' double onClick={() => this.addDigit(0)} />
          <Button label='.' onClick={() => this.addDigit('.')} />
          <Button label='=' operation onClick={() =>this.setOperation('=')} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Tenho quase certeza que o problema está na sintaxe da chamada dessa função no botão:

`<Button label='AC' triple onclick={this.clearMemory} />`

***triple e double eu defini em outro arquivo**

Ja tentei algumas alternativas, mas sempre encontro o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

No react native não existe o evento onClick, e sim o onPress.
Parece que o evento de clique do botão está disparando automaticamente quando o componente é montado, oque causa renderização e fica num loop infinito.
Tenta passar uma arrow function para o onPress do botão

onPress={()=>this.clearMemory()}

Comment: O erro na realidade era o c minúsculo no onClick. Mas obrigado